# Нумерованный список через counter-reset: проблема с выравниванием текста в li

Tags: css

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как выравнить текст внутри li, чтобы вторая строчка начиналась ровно под первой (и не выезжала влево).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.cl_soder_mal {
  width: 200px;
}

.cl_soder_mal ol {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  counter-reset: circle-counter;
}

.cl_soder_mal ol li {
  counter-increment: circle-counter;
  margin-bottom: 1.25rem;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.cl_soder_mal ol li:before {
  content: counter(circle-counter);
  background-color: #DEF6E9;
  width: 2.5rem;
  height: 2.5rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 2.5rem;
  color: #59966E;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 15px;
  position: relative;
  top: -1px;
  margin-left: -2.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="cl_soder_mal">
  <ol>
    <li><a href="#a1">Что такое интеллект?</a></li>
    <li><a href="#a2">Две теории по структуре интеллекта</a></li>
    <li><a href="#a3">Можно ли развить интеллект?</a></li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю поступить следующим образом: для `li:before` изменить `position` на `absolute`, а также отредактировать некоторые отступы. Например так:

```css
ol {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  counter-reset: circle-counter;
}

li {
  position: relative;
  counter-increment: circle-counter;
  padding-left: 60px;
  min-height: 60px;
}

li:before {
  content: counter(circle-counter);
  background-color: #DEF6E9;
  width: 2.5rem;
  height: 2.5rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 2.5rem;
  color: #59966E;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li><a href="#a1">Что такое интеллект?</a></li>
  <li><a href="#a2">Две теории по структуре<br>интеллекта</a></li>
  <li><a href="#a3">Можно ли развить интеллект?</a></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: что поменялось-то?

Comment: В коде что поменялось?

Comment: Добавь пояснения в ответ.

Answer (score 0):

В текущем коде несогласованны единицы отступов, а так же элементы, у которых эти отступы устанавливаются.
В качестве решения можно воспользоваться следующим подходом:

1. С помощью `padding-left` у `ol` забронировать место под счетчик, в этом случае текст перенесенный не будет заходить в эту область
2. сдвинуть, с помощью отрицательного `margin-left` элемент отвечающий за счетчик
3. добавить счетчику недостающий отступ, чтобы выравнять начало текста.

Для примера возьмем отступ в `3rem`:

Тогда сдвинуть нужно будет так же на `-3rem`, в этом случае край счетчика будет совпадать с краем списка.

Так как ширина счетчика `2.5rem`, недостающие `0.5rem` нужно добавить в виде отступа справа.

В итоге код может выглядеть так:

```css
.cl_soder_mal {
  width: 200px;
}

.cl_soder_mal ol {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 3rem;
  counter-reset: circle-counter;
}

.cl_soder_mal ol li {
  counter-increment: circle-counter;
  margin-bottom: 1.25rem;
}

.cl_soder_mal ol li:before {
  content: counter(circle-counter);
  background-color: #DEF6E9;
  width: 2.5rem;
  height: 2.5rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 2.5rem;
  color: #59966E;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
  position: relative;
  top: -1px;
  margin-left: -3rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="cl_soder_mal">
  <ol>
    <li><a href="#a1">Что такое интеллект?</a></li>
    <li><a href="#a2">Две теории по структуре интеллекта</a></li>
    <li><a href="#a3">Можно ли развить интеллект?</a></li>
  </ol>
</div>
```